# TRADACOMS Utility Bill File - Message Specification

Tags: invoice, edi, tradacoms

I am looking for a message definition document for a TRADACOMS UTLHDR message (Utility Bill File, version 3).

Context: Need to setup an ETL process involving generation of UTLHDR message but I am missing the message definition document needed to successfully code / test creation of these files. I am reasonably familiar with EDI formats in general, but without a specification it is 'challenging' to correctly sequence the message segments.

The message type is open / non-propriety, just there seems to be very little published information left despite many hours searching. [TRADACOMS invoice help (EDI Invoice)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408708/tradacoms-invoice-help-edi-invoice) was closest I got, but the tools mentioned do not support the message version I am working with.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The only thing I have is 1992 or 1998 UTLBIL.  Can you get a sample from the trading partner?

Comment: I have been given a single example file so far, I requested some more but not holding my breath - life is never so simple :)

UTLBIL could be useful actually, any chance I can get a copy? Will ping you on G+ if that's ok?

Comment: I can export something for you.  Ping away. :)

Comment: I have the THE UTILITY BILL FILE april 1998 over here. Starts with the UTLHDR. let me know if you want/need it.

Comment: There is a Tradacoms "UtilityBill" example with sample EDI file and some POCO classes in the [Edi.Net](https://github.com/indice-co/EDI.Net) lib. It is written in C#. *Disclaimer I wrote the library*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I cannot find a specification for UTLHDR transaction, the UTLBIL format might get you started in the right direction.  That is available online, or via export from an EDI dictionary.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for providing, it certainly is very helpful!

Eppye - thanks also for your offer; I took a quick look at your bots project,  will investigate that further!